# Keep the method somewhere on the view page, instead of calling it several times

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It's such that I have a method that I call 7 times and I would like the code to be made nicer and at the same time easy to read and understand.

How can I hold it somewhere?

Just pt, I'll do like this.

```
@if(HelperToTables.ContentText.ContentIdValue.GetInfoContentInfo.GetColBool(Model.HiddenId) == true)
     {
         @Html.Raw("col-md-8");
     }
     else if(HelperToTables.ContentText.ContentIdValue.GetInfoContentInfo.GetColBool(Model.HiddenId) == false)
     {
         @Html.Raw("col-md-12");
     }
```

Basically, I think that you could do this here but it does not work in any way.

Note that I do it for example on the **index.cshtml** page.

Comment: Just FYI, you do not need the second condition at all, just use `else` there. Also `== true` is not needed, as that's what `if` evaluates anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I Understand, You call `HelperToTables.ContentText.ContentIdValue.GetInfoContentInfo.GetColBool(Model.HiddenId)` this function many times from the view; Now you want to store the result in any variable then use the variable all the places.

If it is then try this:

```
@{
    var variableName = HelperToTables.ContentText.ContentIdValue.GetInfoContentInfo.GetColBool(Model.HiddenId);
} 

@if(variableName == true)
{
   // do your stuff
}
else if(variableName == false)
{
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: THAT IS BOTH. Thanks many times. It works now! And you have a good day!. I hope u will giv me +1

Comment: I wonder why included that second condition instead of simply using an `else`.

Comment: I am just showing him how to use the `variable` different places; Yes `else` will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the value in a variable.  In this example I use a variable named `flag`.

```
@var flag = HelperToTables.ContentText.ContentIdValue.GetInfoContentInfo.GetColBool(Model.HiddenId);

@if (flag)
{
    @Html.Raw("col-md-8");
}
else
{
    @Html.Raw("col-md-12");
}
```

Comment: Error say: the name does not exist in the current context

Comment: i have complet its.